# ViewLocalizer does not return String

Tags: asp.net-core

On ASP.NET Core 2.0 I have the following:

```
@ViewData.Title("my title");
```

Title is a ViewData extension which adds "my title" to ViewData with key Title.

This is working but I need to localize the title so I did the following:

```
@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer

@ViewData.Title(Localizer["my title"]);
```

But I get the following error:

```
Cannot convert from 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization.LocalizedHtmlString' to 'string'
```

Isn't it strange that I need to call ToString? What am I missing?

Answer (score 14):

> You should be calling the `Value` property instead...
>
> ```
> Localizer["my title"].Value
> ```

This is because `Localizer["foo"]` returns a [`LocalizedHtmlString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization.HtmlLocalizer?view=aspnetcore-2.0) type.

#### LocalizedHtmlString class

```
public class LocalizedHtmlString : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.IHtmlContent
```

This class does not have a converter to string built-in. In addition, I am wondering why you stated that `ToString()` is working for you. I would think it should return `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization.LocalizedHtmlString` rather than the correct value.

Comment: When I added ToString() I didn’t get the error anymore ... That is why I wrote that it works when using ToString

Comment: @MiguelMoura -  I see -- anyway, did this solution work / answer your question?

Comment: @MiguelMoura did this answer your question?